# Find what song is playing in spotify on android

Tags: android, spotify

I want to be able to find out what song is playing in spotify from my application. Is there any way to do this. I read somewhere there might be a way to do this using androids MediaPlaybackService but i really have no idea.

I tried using code found on the website bellow, it works with Google music but not with spotify, so i guess that means that spotify doesn't use MediaPLaybackService. Any ideas?
http://blog.dexetra.com/2010/09/get-current-playing-track-info-from.html

I also found code on this website that allows you to find what songs the user "stars" within the app.
http://mikebevz.com/using-spotify-content-providers-on-android-22161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old post, but it comes up in a google search for this issue. I posted an answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22195867/1345586

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify Android App has no interface that allows you to retrieve metadata about the current playing track.

Answer (score 0):

If you tell the user to scrobble their Spotify songs to last.fm, you can use last.fm's API to get the currently playing track by hitting the [user.getRecentTracks](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks) endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot has changed since this question was answered. Spotify provides a variety of ways to figure out what's playing.

If you're interested in what's playing in the Spotify Android Client specifically, you can use the [Android App Remote SDK](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/android-app-remote/quick-start/). If you're interested in getting the currently playing track on *any* device, you should check out the [Currently Playing Track](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/) Web API.

Hope this helps!