# How is it possible to know what's spotify is playing from an external Android app?

Tags: android, spotify

I just found out this settings option in Spotify for Android settings screen:

> "Device broadcast status - allow other apps on your device to see what
>   you are listening to"

I guess that means any other app can access what's being played via Spotify. How can this be implemented? Is there any documentation around?

Thanks

Comment: Check out [LibSpotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/), it is aC library but you can see an [example](https://github.com/spotify/psyonspotify) were it is integrated on an android app, it can help you.

Comment: thanks i'll have a look

Comment: Anyone from the Spotify team care to answer this? I assume that setting broadcasts an Intent, but we need the action name to be able to use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spotify has the following intent-actions:

metadatachanged,
playbackstatechanged, and
queuechanged.

**queuechanged** contains no extra data. 
**playbackstatechanged** has a boolean value for "playing", and a value for playbackPosition.
**metadatachanged** contains artist, album, track, length, and id values.

You can get Artist, Track, and Album names when the track is changed (manually or automatically) by using **com.spotify.mobile.android.metadatachanged**

If Spotify is paused and started again, only playbackstatechanged is broadcast.

Comment: It looks like this has since changed to `com.spotify.music.metadatachanged` and similar.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me.can you help me with that?

Comment: This is documented at https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-media-notifications/

Comment: Be advised that for your app to receive these data you must authorize Spotify to broadcast. This can be done in the Spotify settings view. See [here](https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2014/07/18/new-android-media-notifications-guide/) for more info ;)

Answer (score 6):

Spotify broadcasts using the standard `com.android.music.metachanged` intent-action.
Register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for that intent-action, then just pick out metadata using

> String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
>   String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
>   String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");

Comment: pretty cool! is this official or is it due to change someday?

Comment: Sense you need to toggle "Device broadcast status" from the app I'm guessing it's here to stay.

Comment: @Freddman Did you mean to type `com.android.music.metachanged`, not `com.android.music.metachange`? Because that's what the Google Music app uses. And is there also a play state change broadcast? Where did you find this info?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry, ofc it's `com.android.music.metachanged`. I did a quick demo-app just to try after reading a blog post which I'm unable to find anymore :/

Comment: This no longer works for Spotify. It works for Google Music, but Spotify does not broadcast on this Action.