# Handling Spotify "metadatachanged" broadcast on Android

Tags: android, spotify

Early versions of spotify broadcasted `metadatachanged` event everytime a track was started to play as it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236358/how-is-it-possible-to-know-whats-spotify-is-playing-from-an-external-android-ap).
However, since one of the last updates it does not send `metadatachanged` broadcast for each track. Instead, it broadcasts `metadatachanged` for a playlist or when queue is changed.

What is correct way to detect a song currently played by Spotify on Android device?

Comment: I work at Spotify, we are investigating the issue as a possible client bug. We'll post back here soon with more information.

Comment: @NikReiman Is there an official documentation for the broadcast stuff? I live in Brazil and since Spotify doesn't work here, it is really hard for me to test without being able to see the actual broadcasts :(

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer is quite late, but I just wanted to note that current versions of the Spotify Android client should broadcast `metadatachanged` at the expected time.

Comment: I have seen that now in metdata the playback position i getting wrong.May i know the reason.Before it was working fine