# Get device playback information

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is it possible to get the information about the current media being played?

For instance, if a song is currently playing on the device (for instance the phone), can one get the information of the song? The name, duration, current position etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this information using Actions on Google, but within Android there are ways you can read the user's notifications or register a broadcast receiver and handle different music apps like in [Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236358/how-is-it-possible-to-know-whats-spotify-is-playing-from-an-external-android-ap/22195867#22195867).

Comment: That would require the user to download an app right? Or would it be able to with using instant apps?

Comment: In addition, is there no way to "query" the assistant for it? Since the assistant can get that information... Essentially what I would like to do is offer a share functionality to audio titles using assistant, do you see a way to do that without have an app installed on the device ?

Comment: You may be able to ask the Assistant what is playing, but that information won't be available to a third-party action.